# How to implement the Unit of Work(UoW) pattern with ADO.NET and use it in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, ninject

I know this question has been asked before, but in those questions there aren't enough details about the actual implementation, so I decided to search for some information about how can this be achieve and this is what I've got so far:

**The IUnitOfWork Interface**:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IDomainTableRepository DomainTables { get; }        
    IVariableRepository Variables { get; }
    IModelRepository Models { get; }     
    IStructureRepository Structures { get; }
    ISentenceRepository Sentences { get; }
    IExpressionRepository Expressions { get; }
    IReturnRepository Returns { get; }

    void Commit();
}
```

**The implementation for IUnitOfWork:**

```
public class SqlUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        const string ConnectionStringName = "DefaultConnection";    
        private AdoNetContext _context;
        private DomainTableRepository _domainTables;
        private VariableRepository _variables;   
        private ModelRepository _models;      
        private StructureRepository _structures; 
        private SentenceRepository _sentences;
        private ExpressionRepository _expressions;            
        private ReturnRepository _returns; 

        public SqlUnitOfWork()
        {
            var connectionString =
                 ConfigurationManager
                 .ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName]
                 .ConnectionString;

            _context = new AdoNetContext(connectionString, true); 
        }       
        public IDomainTableRepository DomainTables
        {
            get
            {
                if (_domainTables == null)
                {
                    _domainTables = new DomainTableRepository(_context);
                }
                return _domainTables;
            }
        }      

        //...getters for the remaining repositories    

        public void Commit()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        #region IDisposable Support
        private bool disposedValue = false; 

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                } 
                disposedValue = true;
            }
        } 
        public void Dispose()
        {            
            Dispose(true);            
        }
        #endregion


    }
```

**The AdoNetContext class**

All the credit for the implementation of this class goes to @jgauffin.

[His original blog post can be found here.](http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/01/unit-of-work-sample-implementation-for-ado-net/)

```
public class AdoNetContext : IDisposable
    {
        private IDbConnection _connection;
        private bool _ownsConnection;
        private IDbTransaction _transaction;

        public AdoNetContext(string connectionString, bool ownsConnection)
        {
            _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            _connection.Open();
            _ownsConnection = ownsConnection;
            _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
        }    
        public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
        {                
            var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = _transaction;
            return command;
        }    
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            if (_transaction == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Transaction have already been already been commited. Check your transaction handling.");
            }
            _transaction.Commit();
            _transaction = null;
        }    
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_transaction != null)
            {
                _transaction.Rollback();
                _transaction = null;
            }    
            if (_connection != null && _ownsConnection)
            {
                _connection.Close();
                _connection = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**The implementation of a repository(DomainTableRepository) that uses AdoNetContext:**

```
public class DomainTableRepository : IDomainTableRepository
    {
        private AdoNetContext _context;    
        public DomainTableRepository(AdoNetContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }    
        public DomainTable Get(int id)
        {
            DomainTable table;
            using (var commandTable = _context.CreateCommand())
            {
                commandTable.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                commandTable.CommandText = "up_DomainTable_GetById";

                commandTable.Parameters.Add(commandTable.CreateParameter("@pId", id));

                table = ToList(commandTable).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return table;
        }    
        public IEnumerable<DomainTable> GetAll(int pageIndex = 1, int pageSize = 10)
        {    
            using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "up_DomainTable_GetAll";
                command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pPageIndex", pageIndex));
                command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pPageSize", pageSize));    
                return ToList(command).ToList();
            } 
        }    
        public int Remove(DomainTable entity)
        {
            using (var command = _context.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "up_DomainTable_Delete";
                command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pId", entity.Id));
                    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }       
    }
```

I apologize for posting so much code,but I want to make sure you understand everything about what I want to ask.

First, I created an interface for the UoW(IUnitOfWork), because in the future I might want to change to an ORM like EF, but since I'm just taking my first step into the the world of back-end programming I wanted to start with ADO.NET and stored procedures.

So here are my questions regarding the implementation of the UoW pattern with ADO.NET and its usage in ASP.NET MVC:

1)Given the code for the **AdoNetContext**(the one that manages the db connection and transactions), **is there any performance penalty for always creating a transaction?**

This is what I read in a SQL book :*"Executing a SELECT
statement within a transaction can create locks on the referenced tables, which can in turn block other users or sessions from performing work or reading data"*  Do the transactions created in C# behave exactly as their counterparts in SQL?

2)As you can see in IUnitOfWork and its implementation (UnitOfWork), I have readonly properties for every repository I have in my application. This a common "pattern" I've seen in lots of tutorials on EF and I found it very convenient since every time I new up a instance of IUnitOfWork I already have access to all its repositories and I don't have to clutter my code with the instantiation of the repositories I need in a specific `Action` (from a `Controller`).

**Do you think it would too much overhead to instantiate all the repositories (as SQLUnitOfWork does) every time I create/inject a new instance of IUnitOfWork?** There are some scenarios in which I might work with 4 or 5 repositories at the same time, but in most cases I'll be using just 1 or 2 in the same `action`.

3) I would like to use DI (maybe Ninject) to inject an instance of IUnitOfWork into my `Controller`s. This way later when I use another persistence framework, I will only have to change this line `kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<SqlUnitOfWork>();` From `SqlUnitOfWork`, to let's say `EFUnitOfWork`.

The problem I've encountered here is that the `Dispose` methods in `SqlUnitOfWork` and `AdoNetContext` are never called and as much as I want to use DI I'd rather wrap the instantiation of `SqlUnitOfWork` in an `using` statement in every `Action` instead of be leaking memory just so that I can use DI.

So this is what I wanted to ask you guys.

I'm trying to learn so please before clicking the close link or marking the question as a duplicate take some time to read my question.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off asking this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I'm not sure this question is very well suited for Stackoverflow. It is too broad and there are too many possible anwers.

Comment: Agree with @Steven, put this on codereview site

Comment: @Steven Can I post it where you're telling me, but keep it here, at least for a couple of days?